# What type of class library to use?

Tags: c#, vb.net, dll, class-library

I want to make a project, using C#, that I can reference in a VB.NET WinForms application. It seems I need to create the C# as a DLL to do so, I'm thinking that means an Assembly (or maybe COM?)

This is my first time attempting such so I have a basic question; what type of project do I need to create?

I'm thinking Class Library, but do I need a .NET Framework one, a .NET standard one, a Portable one, a Universal Windows one or a Windows Runtime Component (Universal Windows)? (the latter two seem unlikely culprits, but then I don't know what I'm at!)

Documentation and articles I've come across so far either assume I already know what type of project to create or just says "create a new Class Library project" -
 but what *type* of class library?

Comment: You don't need dll, but method you use may be different depending on version of VS.  Some versions of VS only support one language and won't allow mixing c# and VB.Net.

Comment: When the documentation does not reveal all the details, you might at least take a few minutes to understand the concepts of different project types. Once the context is clear then the option is obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any documentation and articles that just say "create a new Class Library" predate the plethora of types of class libraries that are now available. Back then, the *only* type of class library was a `.NET Framework` one - so that's what I'd suggest you create now.<sup>1</sup>

At the end of the day, if this turns out to be a bad choice it will not take long to create another class library project and copy the files across from this one.

Also, no COM involved.

---

<sup>1</sup>You could also choose .NET Standard if you want to be "modern" but the choice will not really matter unless you're planning to offer your library as a component for other developers to use.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the normal class library one will work(I believe that one is just .NET, with no special labels in VS), and then you just change what it complies into in the Visual Studio settings. [Maybe this is what you're looking for?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVvFi.png)

Comment: In VS I have here (2017) there *isn't* an option for just a normal "Class Library" they're all listed as "Class Library (<something-something>"